# How to change the picture placed by UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, watchkit, watchos-2

I placed an image on a button (group) and want to change it on button press. But I don't know how? Every code I find (UIImageVew, ...) relies on an image name!?

Thank you for a little hint.

Edit: What I forget to say is, that I am coding with WatchKit for watchOS 2.

Comment: Its not clear from the question, whether you want to change the image of UIImageView or change the image of your button

Comment: I want to change the Image within a Button content type (Button set to "group")

Answer (score 3):

You create the button (with frame):

```
UIButton* myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

you put the button image:

```
[myButton setImage:@"normalImage" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And change the image when the button is pressed:

```
[myButton setImage:@"pressImage" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the image when the button is clicked, you can do like this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked: (id)sender
 {   
     UIButton *buttonObj = (UIButton*)sender;
     [buttonObj setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for so many quick help!!!
It seems, that I am not very keen in my first steps.

What I forget to say is, that I am coding with watchkit (for watchos2).

Inserting

```
UIButton* myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

Gives me "Unknow Identifier UIButton" within the

```
@implementation InterfaceController
```

or

```
@implementation InterfaceController
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay its pretty easy on the button press event method add the below statement,

> [self.yourButtonObject setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"yourImage"] forControlState:
>   UIControlStateNormal]

self.yourButtonObject is the outlet that you created for the button. Creating an outlet is like below.[image]